# Create OAuth 2.0 client id page fields are disabled

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, android-wear-2.0

I'm trying to get an Android Wear watchface set up that gets the number of steps the user has taken.  To do that, apparently I have to get the data from Google Fit.  Step 3 of that process is getting an OAuth 2.0 client id.  I'm following the steps in the link below.

[Request an OAuth 2.0 client ID in the Google API Console](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key)

The first step is clicking the blue ***GET A CLIENT ID*** button.  In there I select my project and click Continue.  That enables the Fitness API.  Then I click on the blue ***Go to credentials*** button.  There I choose Android for where I'm calling the API from and User data for the type of data that I will be requesting.  Then I click the blue ***What credentials do I need?*** button.

This page is where the problem lies.  I am supposed to enter a name, SHA-1 fingerprint and package name.  However, all three fields are disabled so I can't type in them.  If I go ahead and click on the blue ***Create OAuth client ID*** button, it marks those three fields in red with some verbiage about being required.  I still cannot type in the fields.

How is this supposed to work?

Comment: Google?  Google?  anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue today. In case you haven't found a solution to your problem, you can try creating a project with a different Google account. I think it happens because of the conflict with your previous projects.

Comment: I tried it with another Google account but had the same results: the fields are all disabled.  What the hey, Google?

Comment: Do you have any previous projects in your other account?

Comment: Actually, you are correct.  The second account seemed to have a dummy project in it too for some reason.  I used a third account with no projects and it worked.  That is a bug they need to fix.  Thanks for the help.